# AudioKit: dual operation instrument

Tags: audiokit

I am attempting to combine operation generated sounds into a single instrument, I am aware that it is possible to use operations as arguments in each other - but I'm trying to trigger two (or more) simultaneously in the same instrument if possible - so Im trying to do so with a mixer. This is my instrument code:

```
public class LayeredInstrument: MIDIInstrument {

var opGenOne = OperationGenerator {
    let volSlideCurve = Operation.exponentialSegment(trigger: Operation.trigger, start: 1, end: 0, duration: 0.09)
    return Operation.sawtooth(frequency: 880, amplitude: volSlideCurve)
}

var opGenTwo = OperationGenerator {
    let volSlideCurve = Operation.exponentialSegment(trigger: Operation.trigger, start: 1, end: 0, duration: 0.09)
    return Operation.square(frequency: 220, amplitude: volSlideCurve)
}

var mixer = Mixer()

public init(){
super.init()
opGenOne.start()
opGenTwo.start()
mixer.start()
    
mixer.addInput(Node(avAudioNode: opGenOne.avAudioNode))
mixer.addInput(Node(avAudioNode: opGenTwo.avAudioNode))

avAudioUnit = mixer.avAudioUnit
avAudioNode = mixer.avAudioNode
}

public override func play(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber, velocity: MIDIVelocity, channel: MIDIChannel) {
opGenOne.trigger()
opGenTwo.trigger()
}

public func stop(){}
```

}

I have two questions,
1: how come I can take the avAudioUnit and avAudioNode of either of those two operations and use it for a voice but I cant use the mixer (it is silent upon play() at the minute), is there a way to get this to work and hear both voices?

2: a question about operation triggering itself, is it necessary to stop a note played in an operation? if so what's the best way of doing that? possibly have some event at the end of a duration, or a class that monitors all notes played? its just that the examples Ive seen thus far have empty stop() methods